# Is it possible to link two test scripts in IBM Mobile Test Workbench

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw

For example we have an application with a login page.
We recorded two flows: one for transaction of amount, and another for checking the account statement.

In both the flows login page is common. It will be easy if we can generate a separate test script for login and refer it in the beginning of any flow.

My question is: is there any way so that we can link or refer a test script(recording) to run with any other test script(recording)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way out for this.

1. Create a compound test
2. Add the below scripts in a sequential order in compound test
   a. Add Login script 
   b. Add Transaction amount script 
   c. Add Login script 
   d. Add Checking Acc statement script
3. Create a transaction for 2a. and 2b.
4. Create a transaction for 2c. and 2d.
5. Run the compound test

Let's say your Login screen is changed to include new feature, you need to change only the Login script. The change is reflected in Login screen in all transactions.